# associating a pointer with other data

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, graph, shortest-path

Hi so I wasn't entirely sure how to word the topic.

I am implementing a graph for my data structures course. The graph needs to be able to able to find the shortest path between two vertices. The graph compromised of actors as vertices and the edges are movies that actors were together in.

I wanted my data structure to be fast so I thought I could have an actorNode class that stores the name of that particular actor along with a vector of actorNode pointers. Each pointer in that vector represents a movie those two actors were in together. My issue with this implementation idea is would there be a way to associate all the movie information to a particular link between two actors? I need to store both the movie title and the year.

Like if Matt Damon was linked with Ben Affleck for the movie Good Will Hunting (1997).

my actorNode for Matt Damon would have an ActorNode pointer in it's "link vector" to Ben Affleck. Is there a simple way to associate "Good Will Hunting (1997)" somehow with that link between the two ActorNodes?

Thank you!

Comment: Not with only a vector of pointers, no. You need to change your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot attach additional information to a pointer value.
I see two approaches solving your problem:

Approach 1 is analogous to database design, where one would introduce a separate class for such relations, e.g. a class like `class actorsPlayingTogether { Actor *a1; Actor *a2; Movie *m; }`.

Approach 2 would be to introduce a map at class actor, which associates for each of his co-actors the respective movie. So the class actor could be `class Actor { std::map<Actor &,Movie &> coactors; ...}`. Thereby you can get both - the associated actors for fast traversal as well as the respective movies. The drawback is that you store information redundantly, because actor and co-actor both need to refer to each other, and both sides should be consistent.

Hope one of both approaches fits your needs.